# XAP files not cached using HttpClient.GetAsync method in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I just changed the way I was downloading XAP files at runtime in my SL App from using a WebClient to using a HttpClient, since the WebClient does not have a TimeOut option and I was having problems with that in some clients with slow network connections and lots of simultaneous XAP downloads; we use the System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetAsync method to download the XAP files.

Well, the change just worked fine, the connection did not break because of the default timeout, but the we realized that the responses where never cached, so each time we needed to download those XAP files, they where always downloaded from the server. We used Fiddler to certify that the issue was not present with our previous versión using WebClient.

I tried to mess with CacheHeaders in the HttpClient, with no luck.

I saw that there is the possibility to specify some cache policy in C# using HttpWebRequest, and that by default, it comes with the ByPassCache option enabled, although I could not certify if that is true for SL, and also, I could not find that option for Silvelright.

I would be appreciated if anybody could give me any ideas.

Thanks a lot,